# MAKE through Cygwin overloads memory (too many processes)

Tags: python, windows, makefile, cygwin, python-sip

What I'm trying to do is install `SIP 4.14.7` through Cygwin using the make command.  I'm running Python version 3.3.2 (with Python added to the PATH) on a Windows 7 x64 SP1 machine with 4GB RAM and an Intel Core 2 Duo. Since what I'm doing is from within the Cygwin terminal, I'll avoid using the Win32 path format.

Following the installation instructions provided with `sip-4.14.7.zip`, here is what I've done:

1. Uncompressed the .zip into `/c/python33/SIP/`
2. Launched the Cygwin terminal and went to the `/cygdrive/c/python33/SIP/` folder
3. Ran `python configure.py` (No options since I was fine with the default settings)
4. Ran `make install`

As far as I can tell, I followed the instructions as I should have, but obviously I'm not doing something right here.

Here's what happens:[SCREENSHOT](http://imgur.com/ASjKmJD)

The number of `make.exe` processes go up to about 1800 before Windows gets too low on memory and the whole thing reverses itself until there are no more 'make.exe' processes running as shown here: [SCREENSHOT2](http://imgur.com/qxZIA7J)

I've Googled this and searched around here on stackoverflow.com but couldn't find anything related to this particular issue.  It seems that unless using the -j option the MAKE command should only process one job at a time.  I've also tried using the -l option thinking it would limit the processes unless enough memory was available, but the results were the same.

I tried to provide as much detail as possible, but if there is any more information that I should post to help diagnose this issue, I'd be glad to provide it.  Otherwise, any suggestions here would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix-and-match Windows and Cygwin components.  That's not going to work.  What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to get PyQt4 installed, which needs SIP to install.  There are binary installers for PyQt4, but I want to install using the source just so I can understand the process and how it works.

Comment: Using a pure UNIX environment would probably solve any compatibility issues I'm sure, but unfortunately this is not possible for me right now.

Comment: PyQt4 for Cygwin's Python or for Windows'?

Comment: PyQt4 for Windows and the version of Python I installed is for Windows as well.  For PyQt4, only saw source files for Windows, UNIX/Linux, and MacOS/X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Cygwin includes the PyQT4 package (in All->Python within Setup.exe). It's `python-pyqt4` and `python3-pyqt4`. If you are trying to live in Cygwin, I'd install that version into Cygwin and use it. No make required from the looks of it.